# c++ normal_distribution gives different results on different platforms

Tags: c++11, random

This

```
std::mt19937 gen(123);
std::normal_distribution<> distr(0., .2);
printf("%f", distr(gen));
```

prints `0.339167` on my OSX 10.9 machine (built with clang 3.5) but prints `-0.113922` on a linux box (gcc 4.8). I was expecting to see the same results everywhere.

When inspecting the underlying stream from mt19937, I see a consistent sequence of numbers on both platforms. So it appears that the platform inconsistency is in std::normal_distribution.

Is this expected behavior? Is there a way that I can set this up so that I am guaranteed to get the same results everywhere?

Comment: Is that libstdc++ (gcc) resp. libc++ (clang)?

Comment: @Deduplicator yes that's correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::mt19937` and siblings are very specific algorithms. The standard requires that e.g. *The 10000<sup>th</sup> consecutive invocation of a default-constructed object of type mt19937 shall produce the value 4123659995*. There's no wiggle room here.

`std::normal_distribution` and siblings, by contrast, are only required to produce results distributed according to a certain probability density function. There is no requirement for them to be any specific function.